# How do I compare two dynamic arrays and check which elements match?

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to compare two matrices element-wise and return a matrix containing a `1` if the elements in that location match, or a `0` otherwise. I created a simple test function that does this:

```
template <class A, class B>
void func(const A& a, const B& b)
{
    auto c = (b.array() == a.array()).cast<int>();
    std::cout << c;
}
```

So I wrote a `main` function like this to test it:

```
int main()
{
    Eigen::Array<int,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic> b;

    b.resize(2,2);
    b.fill(2);

    auto a = b;
    a(0,0) = 1;
    a(0,1) = 2;
    a(1,0) = 3;
    a(1,1) = 4;

    func(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

 `eigenOperations.cpp: In function ‘void func(const A&, const B&)’:
 eigenOperations.cpp:8:24: error: expected primary-expression before
 ‘int’   auto c = temp.cast<int>();
  eigenOperations.cpp:8:24: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘int’ make: *** [eigenOperations] Error 1`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever marked this as duplicate was right. The problem does arise because I didn't fully understand the C++ `template` keyword.

[Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Replacing the function with the following fixed the problem:

```
template <class A, class B>
void func(const A& a, const B& b)
{
    auto c = (b.array() == a.array()).template cast<int>();
    std::cout << c;
}
```